# Probability of a impressing machine

Tags: probability

> A impress machine can impress $n$ letters. It is activated by eletric impulses, each letter being impressed by  a different impulse. Suppose that there exists a constant probability $p$ to impress the right letter, and also suppose independency between events. One of the $n$ impulses, chosen randomly, was put twice in the machine and, in both times, the first letter was impressed. Calculate the probability that the right impulse was chosen to impress it.

My attempt:

Define the following events:

$\alpha_i =$ the $i$-th letter was impressed for the first time

$\alpha'_i= $ the $i$-th letter was impressed for the second time

$\gamma_i$ = the $i$-th impulse to impress the $i$-th letter was activated.

So we are interested in:$$P(\gamma_1|\alpha_1\alpha_1')=\frac{P(\gamma_1\alpha_1\alpha_1')}{P(\alpha_1\alpha_1')}= \frac{P(\alpha_1\alpha_1'|\gamma_1)P(\gamma_1)}{P(\alpha_1)P(\alpha_1')}$$
since $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are independent.

We may write each $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_1'$ as the disjoint union:

$\alpha_1=\alpha_1\gamma_1\cup\alpha_1\gamma_2\cup...\cup\alpha_1\gamma_n=\alpha_1'\gamma_1\cup\alpha_1'\gamma_2\cup...\cup\alpha_1'\gamma_n= \alpha_1'$.

So it follows:

$P(\alpha_1) = P(\alpha_1|\gamma_1)P(\gamma_1)+P(\alpha_2|\gamma_2)P(\gamma_2)+...+P(\alpha_1|\gamma_n)P(\gamma_n) = \frac{p}{n} + (n-1)\frac{1-p}{n}$

$P(\alpha_1')=\frac{p}{n} + (n-1)\frac{1-p}{n} = \frac{p+(n-1)(1-p)}{n}$

$P(\alpha_1\alpha_1'|\gamma_1)P(\gamma_1)=\frac{p^2}{n}$

Therefore,

$$P(\gamma_1|\alpha_1\alpha_1')=\frac{np^2}{(p+(n-1)(1-p))^2} $$

The book's anwser is different. What's wrong with my response, any hints?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it is asking you to compute the probability that the first letter is indeed the correct letter associated with the impulse that was pushed twice.

You are given that the probability that the impulse, pushed once, gives the correct letter is $p$. Thus, the probability that the impulse, pushed twice, would give the same incorrect letter twice is (using the fact that the events are independent)

$$ \operatorname{Pr}(\text{incorrect letter})*\operatorname{Pr}(\text{same incorrect letter})=(1-p)*\frac{1}{n-1}(1-p).$$

It follows that the probability that the probability that the letter is correct is $1$ minus this, which is

$$ 1- \frac{(1-p)^2}{n-1}.$$